# FoldX PositionScan functions only works for certain position inputs

Tags: protein-structure

I'm using the PositionScan function in FoldX 5.0 to calculate delta delta G for some mutants. I'm working with the command prompt in Windows 10. For some reason, this function will only return output for residues 1-9 of my protein - any residues in the double and triple digits don't work.

For example, my protein only has one chain (A) and it has Leu at position 9 and Lys at position 10. For whatever reason, the following command will work:

```
FoldX --command=PositionScan --pdb=protein.pdb --positions=LA9a
```

While this one won't:

```
FoldX --command=PositionScan --pdb=protein.pdb --positions=KA10a
```

I have triple checked the PDB file itself to make sure I'm not typing in the wrong letter codes and positions. The format of the PDB file seems to be fine, when I open it in a structure viewer nothing seems out of the ordinary.

What's going on here?

Thanks for any help in advance! I'm new at this stuff.

Comment: What happens when you try other commands?
I see and appreciate that you triple checked the PDB file, but it totally sounds like a problem there —e.g. the PDB file is tabulated incorrectly (cf. [PDB ATOM definition](https://www.wwpdb.org/documentation/file-format-content/format33/sect9.html), hence the digit issue.
Say what does the PDB look like after Optimize command (energy minimisation) or PDBFile (a simple roundtrip)? If you get a nonapeptide, then you need to quadruple check!